# Unable to connect to neo4j server on my aws ec2 instance - port 7474

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After installing neo4j on my aws ec2 instance, the following seems to indicate that the server is up.

```
# bin/neo4j console
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1
  config:       /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/conf
  logs:         /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/logs
  plugins:      /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/plugins
  import:       /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/import
  data:         /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/data
  certificates: /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/certificates
  run:          /usr/local/share/neo4j-community-3.3.1/run
Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. 
See the Neo4j manual.
2017-12-01 16:03:04.380+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.3.1 ========
2017-12-01 16:03:04.447+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-12-01 16:03:05.986+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2017-12-01 16:03:11.206+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-12-01 16:03:12.860+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at 
http://localhost:7474/
```

At this point I am not able to connect. I have opened up ports 7474 - and 7687 - and I can access port 80, plus ssh into the instance, etc.

Is this a neo4j or aws problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 2):

Set the dbms.connectors.default_listen_address to be 0.0.0.0, then only open the SSL port located on 7473 using Amazon's ec2 security groups. Don't use 7474 if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Would be nice if the documentation mentioned this early on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Neo4j is only listening on the localhost interface.  If your run `netstat -a | grep 7474` you want to see something like `*:7474`.  If you see something like `localhost:7474` then you won't be able to connect to the port from outside.

Take a look at [Configuring Neo4j connectors](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/).  I believe you want `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address` set to `0.0.0.0`.

And now a warning - you are opening your Neo4j to the entire planet if you do this.  That may be ok but it seems unlikely that this is what you want to do.  The defaults are there for a reason - you **don't** want the entire planet being able to try to hack into your database.  Use caution if you enable this.

Comment: `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0` worked for me. For those of you who are wondering where you should set this value, go to the `conf` folder in your neo4j directory and you'll find a configuration file there.